# JSDOM - set document as a global value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, jsdom

I try to create a JSDOM for jest test, but I encounter some problems,
I would like to make the document/window global, but the text-content is null in my test file.

Here is my code:
JSDOM setting:

```
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const dom = new JSDOM('<!DOCTYPE html><p id="test">Hello world</p>');
global.window = dom.window;
global.document = dom.window.document;
```

But in my test, I tried to print out the text, it returned null

```
console.log(document.querySelector('#test'));
```

It seems that the document is not the one I set as global, is the way I can use to set the document is correct, can anyone tell me what I am doing woring?

I try to define a new global value:

```
global.omg = dom.window.document;
```

it worked in the test file, when I try `console.log(omg.querySelector('#test'));` it printed out Hello world.

The issue is that the way I set global.document value is not correct.

Comment: Your call to `new JSDOM(...)` is having syntax error

Comment: @haim770 I have updated the post...

Comment: Usually you don't need to set up JSDOM manually, Jest can be configured to do this for you.

Comment: @estus Is there a way to pass HTML to JSDOM when it is created? I couldn't find it...

Comment: The same way as you would do with regular DOM. Append and remove.

Comment: Is all of that code inside the same file?

Comment: They are In different files, JSDON setting in setUp.js. Print statement in another test file. @David

Comment: Is it possible that `global` only exists in the `setUp.js` file? Or to ask the other way around: Have you tried to use `global.document.querySelector( ... )` inside your test file?

Comment: It's possibly because Jest already assigns `global.document` on its own, makes it read-only as you would expect from `document` and you cannot reassign it. You can check if `global.document === dom.window.document` after you assign it. Any way, I'd suggest to avoid doing this manually.

Comment: It throws Cannot read property 'textContent' of null @David

Comment: @estus Thanks, it is read-only, return false

Comment: Problem solved after I disabled the built-in JSDOM environment of Jest(testEnvironment: 'node'), the issue is the built-in JSDOM makes the document read-only. Now, I can use the document I set.

Comment: This link answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35100067/3202440