# Change global var inside a JSDom document

Tags: javascript, jsdom

I'm trying create a JSDom document that contains a global var and then trying to change it's value programatically and then print the output again.

My code is the following:

```js
    const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');

    const dom = new JSDOM(`
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <body>
            <script>
                var myGlobalVar = 'foo';
            </script>
        </body>
        </html>`,
        { runScripts: 'dangerously' });

    dom.window.myGlobalVar = 'bar';

    console.log(dom.serialize())
```

I would expect the output to be the same document but with the value of `myGlobalVar` updated to `"bar"`. This is not happening and `myGlobalVar` is still `"foo"`.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and if what I want is possible?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is this a dupe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35099863/setting-global-variables-in-a-script-loaded-by-jsdom

Comment: I don't believe it is. Two different problems as I see it

Comment:  Just checking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dom.window.myGlobarVar = “bar”` sets a property on the window object it doesn’t change the content of the DOM you have provided to the JSDom constructor. If you `console.log(dom.window.myGlobalVar)`, you should see the output as `bar`.

Comment: This is correct. I was misunderstading the tool and how to use it.
Thanks for the help!